# IE/Edge not respecting absolute bottom

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, position, absolute

I have a fairly simple layout, and other browsers seem to do just fine, but both IE and Edge seem to be ignoring my bottom:0 on an absolute positioned div. I've search high and low and implemented some suggested I've found for similar problems (i.e. adding left:0 to the absolute element) but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

```css
.packagebox {
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.leftBox {
  width: 40%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.rightBox {
  width: 59%;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%!important;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

div.boxCTA {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

div.boxCTA a {
  display: table;
  padding: 25px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="packagebox">
  <div class="leftBox"></div>
  <div class="rightBox">
    <h3 class="packageboxTitle">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <p class="price"><span>$100</span> $50 CAD</p>
    <div class="boxlist">
      <ul class="packageboxList">
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="boxCTA">
      <a href="#">Buy Now & Save</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What it looks like on IE/Edge:[image]
How it looks everywhere else: [image]

Comment: If you go into the inspector are the 2 outer divs actually 100% height. Maybe on `packagebox` add `display:flex; align-items: stretch;` (make sure to add the prefixes for all browsers)

Comment: I try to test your above code with Chrome , IE and Edge browser. Here is the result. Edge: https://i.postimg.cc/3JQZ0mPN/151.png, Chrome: https://i.postimg.cc/C5GksrW1/152.png, IE: https://i.postimg.cc/dQr2FDLY/153.png You can notice the similar output across all the browsers. so I think there should be any other css code which is affecting the result and issue is not producible with above posted code. I suggest you find and post the other css code may help to find the cause for the issue.

Comment: @ThomasByy That just decreased the width of both leftbox and rightbox. It appears that in IE, boxCTA thinks that the boxlist div above it is its parent--it's absolutely positioning to the bottom of that div instead of its parent. If I add height to the boxlist div, the boxCTA moves down to the bottom of that new height. Very strange.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thank you so much for trying to replicate. You're right, there is quite a bit more CSS, and it's not impossible that CSS not shown here is causing an issue, but I did my best to remove only what I was certain wasn't relevant.  I think including everything would just be a nightmare for anyone to try to comb through.

Comment: @ThomasByy So after adding min-height:350px to boxlist, this does "fix" the problem, but it still doesn't make sense to me that IE/Edge are confusing parent/child here. Is there a scenario where it would interpret a child as parent aside from the obvious stray div tag?

Comment: @NathanS, If possible for you than try to check all the css properties and attributes and try to checked and unchecked it from developer tools may help you to find the problematic property.

Comment: i have some doubt about min-height + display:table. it should be height:500px, the table-layout algorythm will let it grow if more content is added. also a width might be usefull for the .`packagebox` . See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout to manage width of the tabled container and columns.  **your code works fine in IE11 as i can see from here. boxCta sits at the bottom**

Comment: a jsbin to demonstrate what i wrote earlier http://jsbin.com/xofolujeje/1/edit?html,css,output screen from IE11 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZorLm.jpg